# Assign numbers in matrix to variables then group and calculate Pearson Correlation

Tags: r

I have vectors like so:

```
s <- c("2019")
r <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
t <- c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C", "Team A", "Team B", "Team C")
mgn <- c(33, 56, 63, 43, 12, 15)
score_A <- c(0.330,0.256, 0.118, 0.456, 0.754, 0.257)
score_B <- c(0.584,0.176, 0.342, 0.822, 0.412, 0.147)
score_C <- c(0.118,0.193, 0.286, 0.115, 0.364, 0.587)
df2 <- data.frame(s, r, t, score_A, score_B, score_C, mgn)
```

I also have a matrix like this:

```
numbers <- c(0.25,0.5,0.75)
```

I need to take each of `score_A, score_B, score_C` and multiply by each of the `numbers` in the matrix. for e.g.:

```
score_A * 0.25
score_B * 0.5
score_C * 0.75
```

I would then like to add the scores like so:

```
df2$score_total <- df2$score_A + df2$score_B + df2$score_C
```

And group to create a team total:

```
df2 <- df2%>%group_by(s, r, t)%>%dplyr::mutate(score_Team_Total=sum(score_total))
```

Then create an average like:

```
df2 <- df2%>%group_by(s, r, t)%>%dplyr::mutate(Team_Average=score_Team_Total / 20)
```

What I would like to do then is to group the data by s, r, and show each team with some details and calculate the Pearson like so:

```
(sort by s, r)
         team      score_Team_Total     Team_Average        mgn      
    [1] Team A
    [2] Team B
    [3] Team C
    [4] Pearson (using all the team mgn scores and team_average scores)
```

However I also need to capture all possible combinations of multiplying the scores by the numbers in the matrix.

So in addition to the first example, the others would be be:

```
score_A * 0.25
score_B * 0.25
score_C * 0.25

score_A * 0.25
score_B * 0.25
score_C * 0.75

score_A * 0.25
score_B * 0.5
score_C * 0.5
```

And so on.

I had some help on a previous question, however I can't quite figure this out as I am still new to R.

I tried a loop as follows but it did not quite get me what I need.

```
for(col in 1:ncol(numbers)){ 
    df2$score_A %*% numbers[col]
    print(df1$score_A)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get what you want with one set of `numbers`.
s contains onyl one data (year?), grouping by it does not make much sense, but I have left it in. `score_Team_Total` is the same as the rowsum.

I have chosen to do `cor` of each r with `Team_Average` by `ungroup`, `group_by(r)` , `nest` and then a `mutate` with `map`. At the end you have to `unnest` data and r. For the sake of better showing the results here I have de-selected 2 rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  select(starts_with('score_')) %>% 
  as.list() %>% 
  map2_df(.,numbers, ~{.x *.y}) %>% 
  mutate(rs = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  cbind(df2 %>% select(-starts_with('score'))) %>% 
  group_by(t) %>% 
  mutate(score_Team_Total=rs,
         Team_Average=score_Team_Total / 20) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(r) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(cor =map(data, ~cor(.$mgn, .$Team_Average))) %>% 
  unnest(c(data,cor)) %>% 
  select(-c(rs, s))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#> # Groups:   r [2]
#>       r score_A score_B score_C t       mgn score_Team_Total Team_Average    cor
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct> <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.0825  0.292   0.0885 Team…    33            0.463       0.0231 -0.551
#> 2     1  0.064   0.088   0.145  Team…    56            0.297       0.0148 -0.551
#> 3     1  0.0295  0.171   0.214  Team…    63            0.415       0.0207 -0.551
#> 4     2  0.114   0.411   0.0863 Team…    43            0.611       0.0306 -0.233
#> 5     2  0.188   0.206   0.273  Team…    12            0.668       0.0334 -0.233
#> 6     2  0.0642  0.0735  0.440  Team…    15            0.578       0.0289 -0.233
```

Comment: How can I add the Pearson correlation? I tried `summarize(cor = cor(mgn, Team_Average, method = "pearson")` but it returns all NA values.

Comment: @Michael `cor` requires a numeric vector. What you intend to do is not going to work, as it seems you want to apply `cor` to 2 single numbers. Have a look at `?cor`.

Comment: It is not to 2 single numbers. It is based on each r in the data set. From the above, for r 1, I can do `mgn <- c(33,56,63) ` and `avge <- c(.0231, .0148, 0.0207)  ` then `cor(mgn, avge, method = "pearson") = -0.5509407 `. How can I include this in your solution?

Comment: @Michael I have made a new edit, please have a look.

Comment: great! This is so close! The `score_Team_Total` should only be based on the one line (it isn't for multiple `r's`). So the first line is `0.0825 + 0.292 + 0.0885 = 0.463.` Can the above be adjusted for this? Also, at the beginning you mentioned this is a way to get the desired result with one set of numbers. Can this be used with multiple sets? Possibly with a function or loop?

Comment: @Michael Done. Have a look.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it was most helpful.